# Good mail going to Junk mailbox

Tags: mail.app, email

Frequently and inconsistently, emails are being sent to the Junk mailbox. I have set rules for these emails, but they still end up in Junk. The emails that get sent to Junk are subscribed that I have created separate mailboxes for and set rules to send them to their individual mailbox. This works fine for most emails, but for some bizarre reason, emails from senders beginning with the letter M (e.g. Military.com, Medium Daily Digest.com, etc.) go inconsistently haywire. If I click on the email in Junk and use the "Apply Rules" command it is transferred from Junk to the appropriate mailbox.

At what point are the rules applied? How can I keep this from happening to good emails?

Comment: Have you tried promoting these inconsistent Rules, in case something else is seeing them first & acting on a different Rule? idk at what point they are executed, but once they are they run top to bottom down your list, which is why judicious use of Stop evaluating Rules' is wise.

Comment: There are two sets of rules first those on you mail server an then the rules in your client. Which provider do you use and which client and oos?

Comment: Yes, what @mmm asked. Consider using Outlook client and service.  I’ve found their Spam filtering quite good with very few false positives and the client integrates with the service quite well (meaning it actually learns) when you flag things as Junk/Not Junk.